# Div id not defined

Tags: jquery

I have a from which is wrapped within div element with id "new-task". In some page, I have a div with id "create-new-task". When I click on that, I want a modal dialog for the "new-task" to show, but nothing happens. To make sure that the click() event is functioning properly, I tried showing an alert, and it works fine.

Here's my code:

```
    $("#new-task").dialog(
        {
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 350,
            height: 300,
            modal: true,
            title: 'Add New Task',

                close: function(event, ui) {
                    // do sth when modal dialog closed 
                }
            }
        );

        $("#new-task-link").click(function(){ 
            $('#new-task').dialog('open'); 
            return false;
    });
```

When I try to alert `alert($("#new-task").attr('id'));`, it says **undefined**. Am I missing something here?

Comment: did you `$(document).ready(function(){});`'d?

Comment: ya of course, as i said, i am doing an alert to check, and the alert box shows

Comment: once the page is open in browser, view source of the same and find the div with that id, is it there? if using asp.net and your div is marked runat=server then ID might change

Comment: Seems to work just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/ukpDY/1/

Comment: hmm I guess it works fine like this, but the problem is, the "new-task" id is a form, which is in a different file. i have this link to redirect to that path. <%= link_to 'New Task', new-task, :id => 'new-task-link' %>, its ruby on rails.

Answer (score 0):

I would advice you to view source, and inspect its element id. Given it is ruby on rails, its id would not be changing like every time. And in firebugs' console try to do "$('#elementid');" and see what it gives.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to this problem here:

https://github.com/ramblex/modal-form